# Angular: Insert a component dynamically into a specific place

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using a third party module in which a component uses an HTML input element. I would like to add dynamically an angular component next to this input element, because I need to manipulate the input element.

First attempt was to define a `@Directive` as follows

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'input',
  ...
```

But this isn't applied by angular inside other modules.

Second, inject a component dynamically

```
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);        
    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Then move it into the right place

```
const el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.querySelector('dynamic-comp');
input.parentElement.appendChild(el);
```

with `input` being the input element in question. This seem to work, but I'm wondering if this is a bad idea in the first place and if there is an angular way to do this, or a better hack/solution? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is the input element that you want to manipulate created? Can you add it to an angular view and then add an angular element after it?

Comment: _I need to manipulate the input element._ - manipulate how and why?

Comment: The input element is part of a @components template. This component is part of a third party lib I use. But my app needs to have custom input fields on mobile. So I need to hide the input-field and show my custom component instead.